# c9.io - how to find the host address to make a mysql connection in node.js platform

Tags: mysql, node.js, cloud9-ide

I am trying to host my node.js app in [Cloud 9 Server](http://c9.io). In order to make a mysql connection, I need to know the host address.

[This page](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html)  says in a very absurd (I think I am right ) way :

```
Hostname    $IP     The same local IP as the application you run on Cloud9
```

But where do I get the local IP from ? Nowhere in the docs I found it. Any idea ?

**EDIT :**
I used 127.0.0.1 , 0.0.0.0( from `echo $IP` in the terminal as suggested in an answer) and the values  from  `hostname -I` and  `curl curlmyip.com` in the terminal. 4 different IP addresses. None worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the **[Cloud9 documentation](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html)**:

*You can then connect to the database with following parameters:*

```
Option      Value      Comment
Hostname    $IP     The same local IP as the application you run on Cloud9
Port        3306       The default MySQL port number
User        $C9_USER    Your Cloud9 user name
Password    -          No password since you can only access the DB from within the workspace
Database    c9         The database name
```

**To find out your IP address, open your workspace and type this in the bash console:**

```
curl http://curlmyip.com/
```

Comment: how to find the local IP ?

Comment: where is it in the doc ?

Comment: that command gave in IP. But when used, bash says `{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }`

Comment: Did you try setting up mysql following the blog post in https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/mysql-for-every-workspace/?

Answer (score 0):

Type the following into your terminal:

```
echo $IP
```

That will give you your IP address and you can use that value to connect to your MySQL database from your Node app.

Comment: I get `0.0.0.0` as the IP address and when this is used as the host address, terminal shows 'Access Denied'

Comment: The "Set Up a Database" documentation (more updated than the one I mentioned before) says, "Now you can connect to the database using the ip 127.0.0.1 and the default port 3306". Try connecting with that IP. They're overhauling the docs so inconsistencies will hopefully be gone soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Your workspace URL is

> myworkspace-myusername.c9users.io

(replace myworkspace with the name of your workspace, myusername with your username)

So you can ping that to find out the IP address, or you can just use the URL. Add the port if needed too.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Current, you can use :

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "Your username";
$pass = ""; //blank
$db = "c9"; //or you can create other
```

Answer (score 0):

I have connected from Cloud9 to one remote database (hosted on Fastcomet) by whitelisting (from the host's cPanel) the IP address I retrieved with the command

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

I found that command in this [Coderwall article](https://coderwall.com/p/lyrjsq/extract-your-external-ip-using-command-line-tools)

Note: the same IP address is currently not working to connect me to a different remote database (hosted on Liquidweb). Good luck. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the mysql server as well. The apache and php runner starts it automatically but in node you need to run

mysql-ctl start

first