# what's my host on cloud9 IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following along the hartl rails tutorial book and I'm making a mailer. I'm on the email previews portion right now, and there's this bit of code:

```
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
    host = 'example.com'
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }

inside config/environments/development.rb
```

The instructions say change it to be like `host = 'rails-tutorial-c9-mhartl.c9.io'` but with your own name. I've changed it to rails-tutorial-iylin.c9.io but it's not working (if my name is iylin, shouldn't it be working?). I've found this [c9.io - how to find the host address to make a mysql connection in node.js platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931929/c9-io-how-to-find-the-host-address-to-make-a-mysql-connection-in-node-js-platf) but the top answer there doesn't work either.

Comment: Which is the web address where you are running your cloud IDE application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Chapter 10 in Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, Under section 10.14, what you need to do is go to your c9.io page(if you are using cloud IDE), copy the link in the URL of your cloud server and paste it in this line:

```
host = 'Here should be your c9.io server link'
```

For example: when you start your server on Cloud IDE, it redirects you to a link where you can see your application running, copy that link from the URL and paste it.

If you are working with your local system, you should have a localhost. For example I am working on my local system and my local server is **localhost:3000**. Therefore I should be placing the line as

```
host = 'localhost:3000'
```

Basically your host is where your application is running.

Please let me know if I'm missing something

Below is my c9.io page:
[image]

See the console where command `rails s -p $PORT -b $IP` should start your server. Once it has been started, you'll see a pop up window in the bottom right corner which says your code is running at: "Your application link". That link is your **hostname**.

Comment: hey I just tried this. so I used rails server -b $IP -p $PORT and got mmi-apprails-iylin.c9users.io:8080. When I try to visit the page I'm supposed to,  I get this:  

No route matches [GET] "/rails/mailer/user_mailer/account_activation"

I tried taking the ':8080' part away but that didn't work either. Am I missing something?

Comment: so into your console go to workspace/myapp then type in rails s -p $PORT -b $IP. This should start your server. I think you are getting confused with rails, it's good idea to first read about it here https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning.

Comment: I don't think I got mixed up. I did exactly what you did. What's your URL when you visit your application? Mine is http://mmi-apprails-iylin.c9users.io:8080/

Comment: Hey I sorted it out! I just closed the ide and opened it again. Dunno why that worked but at least it's fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Thank god ! :D Good luck ahead and feel free to contact me anytime if you face problem.